# Data getting scraped and printed is only the first entry of each page but I need all the data

Tags: python, selenium, screen-scraping

I'm having an issue where the code I'm scraping is only printing out the first entry of each page. What I require is that all the data from all three pages of the website get scraped and added to the list 'infoList'.

What I assume is the problem the declaration 'CAR_INFO = 0' but I'm not sure how to fix it. Any tips or push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

my code:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re


DRIVER_PATH = r"C:\Users\salmou\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
URL = "https://vancouver.craigslist.org/"

browser = webdriver.Chrome(DRIVER_PATH)
browser.get(URL)

time.sleep(4)

SEARCH_TERM = "Honda"
search = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#query")
search.send_keys(SEARCH_TERM)
search.send_keys(u'\ue007')


class ScrapedData:
    carInfo = ""
    
    def __init__(self, carInfo):
        self.carInfo = carInfo

    def scrapedCarInfo(self):
        print(SEARCH_TERM + " information: " + self.carInfo)
        print("****")
        

infoList = []


for i in range(0,3):
    content = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".hdrlnk")
    for e in content:
        start = e.get_attribute("innerHTML")
        soup= BeautifulSoup(start, features=("lxml"))
        rawString = soup.get_text().strip()
        # print(soup.get_text())
        # print("*****************************************************")
    button = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".next")
    button.click()
    time.sleep(3)
    
    rawString = re.sub(r"[\n\t]*", "", rawString)

    # Replace two or more consecutive empty spaces with '*'

    rawString = re.sub('[ ]{2,}', '*', rawString)
    
    infoArray = rawString.split('*')
        
    CAR_INFO = 0
    
    carInfo = infoArray[CAR_INFO]
    
    
    objInfo = ScrapedData(carInfo)
    infoList.append(objInfo)


for info in infoList:
    info.scrapedCarInfo()
```

Comment: this might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20028954/scrapy-only-scraping-first-result-of-each-page?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you have 2 loops: external with `i` and inner with `e` but I can't see any reference to the current `i` value in the loop. So it looks like you are performing the same action 3 times.
Also the `rawString` defined and evaluated in the internal loop is treated in the outer loop only. So only the latest value `rawString` received in the inner loop is treated in the outer loop. This may cause your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help! That solved my issue